# Light Fixture Screws & Bracket Too Small for Fixture Box

Tags: light-fixture, screws, mounting

I have a light fixture that came with a mounting bracket and some screws. When I went to screw the bracket into the ceiling fixture box, it looks like the box's holes are too big. Not only do the screws slide right through the hole, but bigger screws won't fit through the bracket holes.

Here is a picture of the box.

[image: box]

Here is a picture of the screw that is supposed to go into the box. You can't tell, but it's way too small!

[image: bracket and box]
Is this common? What is the typical solution to get the screws and mounting bracket to fit onto the box?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an ancient question, but...

It appears that the *other* corners of the box have smaller holes. The ceiling material just needed to be cleared away from them in order for them to have been used.

Comment: I wonder if the larger mounting lip & holes are for ceiling fans.

Comment: I would say not, @P2000. I've mounted plenty of ceiling fans, A) that doesn't look like a fan box - doesn't look thick enough, and B) the mounting screws are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

The ears should be threaded to fit the screws, I can see that they are not. The holes look too big so I would get a bigger screw with a bolt and a lock washer. Put the screw through the channeled section of the bracket and the lock washer and nut inside the box. If the head of the screw is not large enough use a washer.